# Web page sending an email from the user machine

Tags: java, email, java-web-start

I'm looking to create a web page that sends an email from the client machine to an uncontrolled server (not from the server, this is mandatory due to an IP check). This email needs to have specific MIME tags, so "mailto:" is not an option.

I want to do this the cleanest way possible. (The user will trust the web page so is ready to click on any security warning, but repeated warnings would be annoying). Assume that we will only have access to self-signing, even if a trusted certificate might be available in the future.

Java applets seem to be strongly deprecated and no longer supported in some browsers, so I looked at Java Web Start. It seems to be a bit better, but still requirements of whitelisting, and chrome support seems dubious.

Is there any way I overlooked? If i choose to use Java Web Start with all-permissions, what kind of problems am i looking at depending on browser?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to send the email from the server hosting the web-page. You would create a form doe the fields or whatever, post the form the web-server, let the web-server construct the email and send the mail through a sendmail type system or through you local mailserver to the server in question.

Look at JavaMail - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html

If you are using Spring Boot or Spring you could use their mail implementation - http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-email.html

Comment: This is not possible. The mail need to be sent by a specific IP which is the client IP. The server can not send this email.

Comment: That is going to pose a challenge to you and I am not sure you can do it. I have never found the need to do something like this and I wish you the best of luck.